# NoClassDefFoundError Java When all fines exists in the classpath

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

```
$ ls
Dockerfile  Service1.class  Service1.java  socket.jar  tp/

$ java Service1 -jar socket.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: real/connector/view/FunctionHandler
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: real.connector.view.FunctionHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

I have put everything in place. Still seem to getting this error. Can anyone please suggest

Comment: Try: `java -cp "socket.jar"  Service1`

Comment: $ java -cp "socket.jar" Service1
Error: Could not find or load main class Service1

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Tried. Cant find main class.

Comment: What is the FQCN of Service1?

Comment: its classname. public Class Service1{}

Comment: Service1 has a package? for example `com.services;?`

Comment: No. It just imports from socker.jar jar.

import real.connector.view.FunctionHandler;
import real.connector.view.ServiceHandler;
import real.connector.worker.service.Function;
import real.connector.worker.service.Service;

public class Service1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
ServiceHandler svc = new Service("Data1", 4010);
FunctionHandler fc = new Function("getDynamicValue", System.currentTimeMillis() + " Value");
FunctionHandler fc1 = new Function("getStaticValue");

svc.registerFun(fc);
svc.registerFun(fc1);
svc.post("Data is out");

svc.start();
};

}

Comment: Service1 does not contain any package

Comment: `$ java -cp . Service1`

Answer (score 0):

Setting CLASSPATH helped.
I set CLASSPATH as export CLASSPATH=/c/Users/Sufi/docker/socker.jar**:.**

I had missed :. in the end. Now its working good.